# How to add scrollbar or scrollview in android with class java not xml?

Tags: android, scrollbar, scrollview

How to add scrollbar or scrollview in android with class java not xml this code?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.srvr, null);
layout = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout1);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams labelLayoutParams = new  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

layout.setLayoutParams(labelLayoutParams);

labelLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    labelLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    labelLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    labelLayoutParams.leftMargin=120;

   final EditText tt = new EditText(this);
      tt.setTag(i);
      tt.setText(DisplayName_list[i].toString());
      tt.setMinWidth(230);
      tt.setMaxWidth(230);
      tt.setMaxLines(1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood well you want to create a ScrollView programatically. You create it as any other views:

```
ScrollView sc = new ScrollView(this);
sc.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
sc.setFillViewport(true);
```

And then you have to add to it your view. Make sure that your view you are adding to the ScrollView is a root view.

```
sc.addView(ROOT_VIEW)
```

In your case ROOT_VIEW is a layout which is RelativeLayout

Comment: When I add a layout which is RelativeLayout, I take this error: "ScrollView can host only one child"  What can I do??

Comment: Exactly that will happen if you add to ScrollView more than one child. That's why I said to make sure that you are adding to the ScrollView the parent view. Check in your xml file your parent view, then findViewById and add it as shown in my answer. Or You might also want to firstly add tt EditText to layoutand then layout to ScrollView. To do so use the same addView()method

Comment: layout.addView(spin,labelLayoutParams);
LL.addView(layout);
sc.addView(LL);
setContentView(sc);  I tried both methods but I take another error :   "You must call removeview() on the child's parent first."

Answer (score 0):

include this as parent

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

// Here should b your Layout tag

```
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp" />
```